# How can I evaluate console.log(1+2) inside eval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, eval, command-line-arguments

Im trying to send a parameter via node console and want to execute it inside eval function.

What im writing in the console is this:

```
node main console.log(1+1)
```

The main.js file is this:

```
var x = "";
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
  x = val;
});

var eval = require('eval')
eval("(" + x + ")");
```

And it throws this error:

```
D:\Sandbox\jsdom>node main console.log(1+2)
0: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
1: D:\Sandbox\jsdom\main
2: console.log(1+2)

evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
(console.log(1+2))
 ^
ReferenceError: console is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:2
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:41:15)
    at module.exports (D:\Sandbox\jsdom\node_modules\eval\eval.js:69:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Sandbox\jsdom\main.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

The output that im expecting in console is:

```
3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `console` `scope` through to `eval`. For example:

```
var x = "";
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
  x = val;
});

var eval = require('eval')
eval(x, null, 'console');
```

When called with:

```
node app.js "console.log(1+1)"
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

Comment: No problem!! :)